# I get ValueError: 'Dip Time' is not in list

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have my csv file like;

```
  Site,Tank ID,Product,Volume,Water Level,Temperature,Ullage,Dip Time
    abc,1,ADO,35302.00,0.00,19.10,14697.00,18/09/2019 07:54:54 a.m.
    xyz,2,ADBLU,1014.00,0.00,14.80,3985.00,18/09/2019 07:54:54 a.m.
```

I try to process them using panda.

```
def read_dipsfile(writer):
    atg_path = '/Users/ratha/PycharmProjects/data/dips'
    files = os.listdir(atg_path)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    dateCol = ['Dip Time']
    for f in files:
        if(f.endswith('.CSV')):
            print (f)
            data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(atg_path, f), delimiter=',', skiprows=[0], parse_dates=dateCol)
```

..

I get following error;

```
File "/Users/ratha/PycharmProjects/LOADER/DataProcessor.py", line 64, in processFiles
    read_dipsfile(writer)
  File "/Users/ratha/PycharmProjects/LOADER/DataProcessor.py", line 51, in read_dipsfile
    data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(atg_path, f), delimiter=',', skiprows=[0], parse_dates=dateCol)
....
      File "/Users/ratha/PycharmProjects/venv3bploader/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2027, in _set
        x = names.index(x)
    ValueError: 'Dip Time' is not in list
```

Why is that, dip Time is one of my column name?

Comment: I think one of file have no column `Dip Time`

Comment: You can easy test it. First remove `parse_dates=dateCol` and then add `print (data.columns.tolist())` after `read_csv`. Is possible all file have column `Dip Time`, only one file missing

Comment: And if still problem, is possible share files? Only first 3 rows and mainly columns names of all files in folder?

Comment: @jezrael Thanks, After changing skiprows=[0] to skiprows=[1] it works.. I dont know how..There was no any extra rows on top

Comment: Yes, from your sample data `data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(atg_path, f), parse_dates=dateCol)` should working